# What does this simple command means in PHP?

Tags: php

I have found this command written in PHP, but I cannot understand what it does... I have seen an introduction to arrays for PHP, but still, I can't figure this out.

```
$from=1;
$A['from'] = $A[$from];
```

What is the programmer here doing?
I mean, how he can assign $A[$from] somewhere, since $A[$from] has not get any values (array A is not used before). And what this command does?

Comment: If the $A is not yet initialized, then programmers are not doing anything at all. I suspect this is only to help you get in touch with assoc vs vars names when they're same.

Comment: If `$A` hasn't been defined before, it looks like bad code. There isn't any fancy trickery going on here. The value of `$A[1]` is being inserted into `$a['from']`. If `$A[1]` isn't set, this will result in an error (Errr...notice).

Comment: It won't result in an error, it will result in a notice: undefined index.

Comment: @Popnoodles Picky picky :) I would consider anything that I didn't intend the user to see as an error - notices, warnings, errors.

Comment: @Fluffeh It's not picky. In a dev vs production environment an error may prevent an end user from doing something, but a notice will only show to developers and not stop the code dead. There's a rather large difference between the two.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments.! He also has this error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors',0); above of his code... is this just to avoid this kind of errors?

Comment: Avoiding errors produces bad code. Jim can you show us the code from the point where `$A` is defined, something like `$A = array();`

Comment: it is not defined at all. It is used first time there...

Comment: And that file isn't included by another file that DOES define it? If not, and you're sure it's not it should read `$A = array('from' => 1);` You were right to question it.

Answer (score 2):

This code mean

You have variable  form have value = 1 
and you have array with key that's mean

$array['key']=1

that was example

with your code

$form = 1 // this is variable have value = 1
$A['form']=$a[$form] // give key form value of variable form it's mean

echo $A['form']; // it will show you 1 witch is value of variable $form .